# git for windows ssh credentials not working for gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, openssh

**The situation:**

Existing user/repository/git remote server, setting up environment on a new pc using git for windows.

**The problem:**

When I try to do basic git commands in git bash that require access permissions, I get the prompt:

```
git@gitlab.local's password:
```

Which in my experience means that the SSH connection using RSA key isn't set up correctly.

**Steps I already took:**

1. I made sure user.name and user.email are correctly set in git config
   and verified using "git config --global --list"
2. I tried re-generating a ssh_key running  and adding to gitlab. then saved it to another file (not the default id_rsa). then
   added using the steps :     `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"&ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new`
   Which got successful  "Identity added: "

Manually adding credentials is problematic security wise so I rather not go there.

I've done this setup process many times and am baffled what could be the cause for the SSH connection not working seamlessly.

Comment: The usual diagnostic is to run `ssh -T` or `ssh -Tv` (add more "v" letters for more verbosity): `ssh -T git@github.local` will test out the ssh connection without involving Git at all. If that works the way you want, then on Windows, the usual problem is that Git and Windows each come with *their own* ssh, and one is set up correctly and the other is not, so convince Git to use the correct ssh and/or set up the other one too.

Comment: If that *doesn't* work the way you want—e.g., if it demands a password or pass-phrase on the wrong system, despite having the agent running—you can debug from there without Git in the way.

Comment: It sounds like you may have multiple OpenSSH / bash / git installations as torek mentioned. How are you accessing git? How did you run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"&ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new` You probably want to know: (1) where is your git binary (`where git`) and (2) where is your `ssh-agent` you're executing (`which ssh-agent`). Also did you upload your key to GitLab? I recommend [following the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) carefully

Comment: As per @torek suggestion, I used `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.local` to see why it failed using the ssh key. 
The error was:  `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm`  .
This was solved in my case by adding: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` to git config file.

Answer (score 2):

The comments led to an answer:

> As per @torek suggestion, I used `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.local` to see why it failed using the ssh key. The error was: `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm`. This was solved in my case by adding: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` to git config file.

Technically, you added this to your *ssh* configuration, not your Git configuration.  (You *can* set up the same bypass trick via Git, but the spelling is different.)

This means your server (not client) is at fault here: it is using a weak SSH RSA public key.  See https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2 and/or https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html for additional information.

If possible, you should upgrade the ssh server on the server system.